# How to build a structure for Parameters?

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking for a proposal for a data structure.

I have used different tables for different parameters. For example one table for cities, and one for emplyees and one for departments and so on.

Since this is not comfortable, I have changed this to just a single table like

```
id;
File_id;
Param_Name
Param_val
```

where `File_id` is integer and it means what is this parameter for, ie `101` it is a city, `102` it is department and so on.

Is this enough or how can I forward one step more (if you have better idea)?

Comment: you might be interested in http://wikis.gm.fh-koeln.de/wiki_db/Datenbanken/KeyValueSysteme, but for usual Applications it won't be the preferred way

Comment: Or perhaps [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model).

Comment: You'd better give us some more background about your app and the database you use, because you're violating the principle of database normalization, which might give you big trouble later on. What specifically is "not comfortable"?

Comment: if this is a database question, why is this tagged with Delphi and pascal tags?

Comment: This way, you solve the problem of having a fixed number of attributes for an object, but you create several new ones. You cannot simply get all values for an object into a single tuple, and you cannot enforce each attribute to have a value via simple constraints that your DBMS provides. Also joining to other tables quickly turns into a maintenance nightmare. Sooner or later we all invent this structure, and sooner or later we all find out that it defeats the purpose of using a relational database. :) My advice: don't do this.

Comment: I removed the `delphi` and `pascal` tags, as your question has absolutely nothing to do with either of them. Please use only tags that apply to the question you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: i used tags coz im coding in delphi....